# how to get multiple value (how get second matching data)

Tags: vba

i am working on this code below

i try to get data from another workbooks sheet1
my problem is there are two ” Financial Depth” with different value in workbook sheet1
how i can get them two different cell

example

Financial Depth=10.000

Financial Depth=24.000

this code get first value .(Financial Depth=10.000)......

```
Sub Balance()
Dim I As Integer
Dim myfile As String

Pathname = “E:\test\”
I = 1
myfile = Dir(Pathname & “*.xls”)
Cells(1, I) = myfile
StartingPoint:
I = I + 1
myfile = Dir
Cells(I, 1) = myfile
If myfile “” Then GoTo StartingPoint
I = I – 1

For K = 1 To I
‘On Error Resume Next
‘ *** workbook name***
Filename = Cells(K, 1)
Workbooks.Open (Pathname & Filename)
‘ *** company name ***
Cells(K, 2) = Workbooks(Filename).Worksheets(“Sheet1″).Cells(1, 1)
‘ *** Financial Depth***
Cells(K, 3) = ” Financial Depth”
For g = 1 To 220
If Workbooks(Filename).Worksheets(“Sheet1″).Cells(g, 1) = ” Financial Depth” Then
Cells(K, 4) = Workbooks(Filename).Worksheets(“Sheet1″).Cells(g, 3)
Exit For
End If
Next g




Workbooks(Filename).Saved = True
Workbooks(Filename).Close




Next k
End Sub
```

Comment: Remove the `Exit For` and figure out where you want to put the second value

Comment: thanks you ...it works certainly

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

```
Sub Balance()
Dim I As Integer
Dim myfile As String
Dim m as Integer
m = 4
Pathname = “E:\test\”
I = 1
myfile = Dir(Pathname & “*.xls”)
Cells(1, I) = myfile
StartingPoint:
I = I + 1
myfile = Dir
Cells(I, 1) = myfile
If myfile “” Then GoTo StartingPoint
I = I – 1

For K = 1 To I
‘On Error Resume Next
‘ *** workbook name***
Filename = Cells(K, 1)
Workbooks.Open (Pathname & Filename) 
‘ *** company name ***
Cells(K, 2) = Workbooks(Filename).Worksheets(“Sheet1″).Cells(1, 1)
‘ *** Financial Depth***
Cells(K, 3) = ” Financial Depth”
For g = 1 To 220
If Workbooks(Filename).Worksheets(“Sheet1″).Cells(g, 1) = ” Financial Depth”         Then
Cells(K, m) = Workbooks(Filename).Worksheets(“Sheet1″).Cells(g, 3)
m = m +1
End If
Next g
```